# Uploading PDF with FTP and it gets messed up - Android

Tags: android-studio, pdf, server, ftp, ftp-client

Currently, I'm trying to upload PDF files with the FTPClient in Android. 
All of the PDFs from the Internet are working just fine, but documents from my university are getting messed up. What could cause this problem?

I'm using a simple AsyncTask with the standard FTP.Client Code.

Really appreciate your answers, hope you can help me!

[image: Example one]

[image: Example two]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some PDFs contain binary data and others do not.

Set your transfer type to Binary.

Comment: Patrick, Did you try setting the transfer type to Binary? Are you still having issues?

Comment: Thank you for helping me out!